# Using CloudFlare with a mirror site

Tags: mod-rewrite, cache, mirroring, cloudflare

I am developing a mirror website (where people can download files, sort of like a FTP). I was wondering about using CloudFlare to help cut down on bandwidth usage. I have the mirror website with mod_rewrite, so that when a user goes to http://www.example.com/xyz/file.zip it is  redirected to http://www.example.com/download.php?path=xyz&file=file.zip which increments the number of downloads and outputs "file.zip". Here is the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/((.*)(.zip))$ /download.php?path=$1&file=$2
```

I was wondering if I use CloudFlare on this website, will it pretty much render the .htaccess file useless and PHP code useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on this page, Cloudflare don't cache zip files](https://cloudflare.tenderapp.com/kb/top-frequently-asked-questions/which-kind-of-file-extensions-does-cloudflare-cache).  If the zip files are most of your bandwidth, CloudFlare won't save you much.

The RewriteRule you supplied above does not do a redirect.  For a redirect, you would need something like `[R]` or `[R=301]` after the rule.

If you find a competing service that *does* cache zip files for you, the redirect might be the right way to achieve both your goals.  Send the downloader a link to `http://www.example.com/xyz/file.zip` as you are currently doing (leave in the rewrite that has a PHP file serve this page) but have the PHP send back a *redirect* (HTTP 302 or 303 response code) sending them to `http://www.example.com/realpath/file.zip`.  Their client will then make a new request for that URL and will actually get the file.